# Ruby On Rails: creating a new record brings up a error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

I'm Struggling to see where I'm going wrong with this statement 
I have used the same syntax to create other records in my database.
However I have not had an issue with using => or commas until now.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
irb(main):006:0> me = AdminUser.create (:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user", :username => "tuser")

SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'
...dminUser.create (:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user"...
...                               ^
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
....create (:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user", :usern...
...                               ^
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space

me = AdminUser.create(:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user", :username => "tuser")

Comment: ...Your kidding, of all the silly things I could have done.

Comment: that kind of things happen... sometime you just need a little break ;)